# Модификация функции

Tags: javascript

Написать код функции modificator, чтобы в результате работы кода:

```
function sampleFunc () {
    console.log ( `${arguments.callee.name}: ${arguments[0]} | ${arguments[1]}` )
}

function modificator ( func ) {
    ...
}

testFunc = modificator( sampleFunc )

testFunc()
```

в консоли было:

```
sampleFunc: test | sample
```

Comment: И что? Вопрос то в чём?

Comment: подскажите в этом примере нужно применять Каррирование?

Comment: Для начала добавьте ваш вопрос в вопрос. И изложите его более подробно.

Comment: скорее частично применение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `sampleFunc` выводит два переданных ей аргумента.

В соответствии с необходимым выводом, функцию нужно вызвать с параметрами `test` и `sample`

Результатом `modificator` должна быть функция, при вызове которой, вызовется `sampleFunc` с указанными параметрами.

Исходя из вышеописанного функция `modificator` может быть такой:

```
function modificator ( func ) {
    return function (){
        func('test', 'sample');
    }
}
```

Так же можно воспользоваться методом [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
function modificator ( func ) {
    return func.bind(undefined, 'test', 'sample');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!